# Replace HTML tag through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following trackbar.

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
        <link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/dependencies/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<input id="ex19" type="text"
      data-provide="slider"
      data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]"
      data-slider-ticks-labels='["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"]'
      data-slider-min="1"
      data-slider-max="12"
      data-slider-step="1"
      data-slider-value="6"
      data-slider-tooltip="hide"/>

      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
       <button id="myButton">Change bar</button>
```

If I click the button , the trackbar will be updated with new values

```
 data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]"
      data-slider-ticks-labels='["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio"]'

      data-slider-min="1"
      data-slider-max="6"
      data-slider-step="1"
      data-slider-value="3"
      data-slider-tooltip="hide"/>
```

I do not want to go with futher details because the project it's very complex and it tends to confuse. I'm getting stuck with the above. Thanks for help.

This is some code I found in JS:

```
var Labels = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo"];
$('#myButton').click(function() {
$('.slider-tick-label').each(function(index) {
$(this).text(Labels[index]);
});           
});
```

I guess it doesn't work because I need to get all tag updated with the proper information.

Comment: You're stuck? what does that mean? please specify what you're stuck with

Comment: I dont have idea how to solve the issue, could please give me some orientation.

Comment: @N'oel what specifically are you "getting stuck" with? You haven't said what isn't working and you haven't given us all of your code, so it's almost impossible to help if we don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Ok let's put it in this way, I have this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nacs2025/L7pn58rt/   Please do the following, create a button when you click the button the slider must change to: "January- May ", so far the example is in spanish (from January to december) nevertheless the language it's not the main thing here. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's code you're not showing us, '.slider-trick-label' doesn't exist